# create-react-app & react-slick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-slick

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { Slider } from 'react-slick';

import Home from './Home.js';
import About from './About.js';

class App extends Component {


  render() {
    var settings = {
      dots:true,
    };
    return (
      <div className='app'>

        <div className='container'>
          <Slider {...settings}>
            <Home />
            <About />
          </Slider>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

[Picture of errormessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TU3Ls.png)

So I cant make my slider work... Even ready examples wont work. Theres picture of error what react throws. Im using create-react-app

Comment: Put the error message in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try `import Slider from 'react-slick';` (remove the braces)

Answer (score 1):

Actually the braces are used when you want to import something specific from the package in your case you can just:

```
import Slider from 'react-slick';
```

I hope that helps in understanding what you are doing as well :-)